# Sub query to count number of time an id appears in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using SQL Server 2012. I have a table called deals that contains a primary key called deal_id along with 10 other fields. I also have a table called deals_country that contain a foreign key called deal_id.

It's possible that a record in deals contains numerous records in deals country. What I want to do is to count the number of times every deal_id from deals appears in deals_country?

Below is what I have tried without success.

```
 select MA_DEALS.*, MA_DEALS_COUNTRY.mycount
 from MA_DEALS cross apply
 (
select count(MA_DEALS_COUNTRY.deal_id) as mycount
from MA_DEALS_COUNTRY
group by MA_DEALS_COUNTRY.deal_id   
  ) MA_DEALS_COUNTRY
 order by MA_DEALS.deal_id
```

Comment: mysql or sql-server - and consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you can use `CROSS APPLY` for this, I would start with the basic `JOIN` and `GROUP BY` query instead:

```
select MA_DEALS.*, dc.mycount
from MA_DEALS d left join
     (select dc.deal_id, count(dc.deal_id) as mycount
      from MA_DEALS_COUNTRY dc
      group by dc.deal_id   
     ) dc
     on d.deal_id = dc.deal_id
order by d.deal_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT  D.*,
        DC.N
FROM MA_DEALS D
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT deal_id, COUNT(*) N
            FROM MA_DEALS_COUNTRY
            GROUP BY deal_id) DC
    ON D.deal_id = DC.deal_id
```